# Post flag history overflows the screen in the case of long unbroken comments

Tags: bug, comments, design, moderator-tools

I had a user post an abusive post today, and a comment in similar vein underneath it. The comment gathered a few offensive and VLQ flags, which I wanted to review once I'd deleted the comment. It contained no spaces, i.e. was an unbroken word. When I went to look at the flag history for the post, this happened:

[image]

Because it was unbroken, the content of it caused the Comment column to overflow the standard limit on width, and actually overflow the edge of my screen itself. Being that this is  a1600x900 monitor, there's plenty of space on it.

If a comment is unbroken this long, perhaps we could break the word up?